# Check routedata.values for all keys

Tags: asp.net, routes

I made a routing like *Login/{id}/{hash}/{gen}/{dt}* (this is for auto identification).

When I use URL *"Login"* and *"Login/value1/value2/value3/value4"*, it works very fine.

But in case, when I use just one, two or three routing values, it gives me Error 404.

For example, *"Login/value1"*, *"Login/value1/value2"* and *"Login/value1/value2/value3"* occurs an Error 404 (Page not found).

So what I need is if the url mismatches with a full routing url, I need to redirect to the *Login* instead of *PageNotFound* page.

*"Login/value1"* ==> *"Login"*

*"Login/value1/value2"* ==> *"Login"*

*"Login/value1/value2/value3"* ==> *"Login"*

My code as follows:

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("id") &&
    Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("hash") &&
    Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("gen") &&
    Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("dt"))
    {
        if (CheckUsersData())
        {
            Session["id"] = Page.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Home");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("~/Login"); //if auto identification data (route values) is incorrect
    }
else
    Response.Redirect("~/Login");
```

Thanks in advance!

**NOTE!!!** Of course, I can register three more routes in a *global.asax*, but I would like to find (possible) better solution.

Comment: I tried to google, I tried to look up here, but no similar question. I just saw a question, how to redirect to PageNotFound page, but I don't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added three more routes, so resulting routing is:

```
Login/{id}
Login/{id}/{hash}
Login/{id}/{hash}/{gen}
Login/{id}/{hash}/{gen}/{dt}
```

And code as simple as

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("id") &&
    Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("hash") &&
    Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("gen") &&
    Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("dt"))
    {
        if (CheckUsersData(/*my_arguments_here*/))
        {
            Session["id"] = Page.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Home");
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("~/Login"); //if auto identification data (route values) is incorrect
}
```